# declare array using dynamic variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery:

```
 $(function() {
    var $used_social_medias = [];

    $('.social_medias input').click(function() {
        var $data_icon = $(this).attr('data-icon'); //

        console.log($data_icon);

        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            eval('$used_social_medias['+$data_icon+']='+$data_icon);

            console.log($used_social_medias);
        } else {
            eval('delete $used_social_medias['+$data_icon+']');

            console.log($used_social_medias);
        }
    });
})
```

`eval('$used_social_medias['+$data_icon+']='+$data_icon);` AND 
`eval('delete $used_social_medias['+$data_icon+']');` is NOT working..

How can I declare array using dynamic variables?

Comment: What's `$data_icon`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `eval` so remove it.

To add an element to an array use the `.push()` method:

```
$used_social_medias.push($data_icon);
```

To remove an element use `.splice()`:

```
$used_social_medias.splice($used_social_medias.indexOf($data_icon), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if($(this).is(':checked')) {
   $used_social_medias.push($data_icon);
   console.log($used_social_medias);
} else {
   $used_social_medias.splice($used_social_medias.indexOf($data_icon), 1);
   console.log($used_social_medias);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var data = "testVariable";
eval("var temp_" + data + "= new Array();");
temp_testVariable[temp_testVariable.length]="Hello World";
alert("Array Length: " + temp_testVariable.length);
alert("Array Data: " + temp_testVariable[0]);
```